# como pasar variables de scrip que inteprete una sentencia sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, script

Buenas es la primera vez q participo estoy queriendo hacer que las variables : xco, xto, xde, xcc me reconoscan en la consulta sql q hago mas abajo en vsql, no se sisera posible si me pueden dar una mano o alguna idea para poder encontrar ese camino, gracias de antemano

```
function mostrarValores()
            {


                xco = parseFloat(document.getElementById('idcondominio').value);
                xto = parseFloat(document.getElementById('idtorre').value);
                xde = parseFloat(document.getElementById('iddepartamento').value);
                xcc = parseFloat(document.getElementById('idconcepto_consumo').value);


                var vsql = '<?php echo $sql=DB::table('costo_condominio_mensual')->select('Pago')->where('idcondominio','=',  xco)->where('idtorre','=',xto)->where('iddepartamento','=', xde )->where('idconcepto_consumo','=', xcc )->get(); ?>'
                $("#consumo").val(vsql)

            }
```

Comment: que error te sale ?

Comment: bueno sale este error: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Use of undefined constant xco - assumed 'xco' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP), le he puesto entre '' la variables pero me sale vacio xq interpreta q estoy comparanco xco y no con el valor de xco

Comment: perame ya te ayudo con  el code

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero caballero, el document en PHP no EXISTE!!!

Existe el lado del cliente y el lado del servidor.. No puedes mezclar 2 cosas a la vez. Cuando escribes código JavaScript es el navegador quien lo interpreta, una ver¡z el procesador PHP lo ha procesado, es decir, intentas introducir variables JavaScript que aún no han sido procesadas en código PHP. Vamos, que no se puede...
Un saludo. Te recomiendo que te veas algunos videos. https://www.youtube.com/user/codigofacilito/videos

Comment: gracias bro todas las repuestas son de ayuda, si puiedieras sugerir como podria hacer seria genial gracias por tu aporte, seguire revisando y gracias por el link

Comment: no uses mayúsculas continuas equivale a gritar

Answer (score 0):

Mira puedes llamar variables de JS a PHP y viceversa, te muestro un ejemplo:

**De PHP a JS**

```
<?php $variablePHP = “contenido de la variable php”; ?>
<script>
var variableJS = “<?php echo $variablePHP; ?>” ;
document.write(“VariableJS = ” + variableJS);
</script>
```

**De JS a PHP**

```
<script> var variableJS = “contenido de la variable javascript”; </script>
<?php
$variablePHP = “<script> document.write(variableJS) </script>”;
echo “variablePHP = “.$variablePHP;
?>
```

Solo tienes que asegurarte de mandar a llamar correctamente (la dirección donde se encuentren) los archivos JS y PHP

Y una vez obtenidas las variables puedes usarlas en tu sentencia SQL

Comment: gracias por la contestar ya probe ese pero en la sentencia sql no lo reconoce solo lo toma como cadena..

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede, es que cuando cargar el documento el php ya se ha cargado en el servidor, (php se carga del lado servidor y js del lado del cliente), por ende cuando llega a la funcion el php ya se ha cargado y el SQL no tomara efecto, por ende no traera nada, yo tuve el mismo problema y lo solucione con ajax... seria algo asi:
creas un archivo php con nombre mi_nuevo.php, en el cual ira todo lo de php y a lo ultimo das un echo..

```
xco = $_POS['xco'];
xto = $_POS['xto'];
xde = $_POS['xde'];
xcc = $_POS['xcc'];

$sql=DB::table('costo_condominio_mensual')->select('Pago')->where('idcondominio','=',  xco)->where('idtorre','=',xto)->where('iddepartamento','=', xde )->where('idconcepto_consumo','=', xcc )->get();

echo $sql;
```

y asi quedaria tu documento inicial

```
function mostrarValores()
        {
            xco = parseFloat(document.getElementById('idcondominio').value);
            xto = parseFloat(document.getElementById('idtorre').value);
            xde = parseFloat(document.getElementById('iddepartamento').value);
            xcc = parseFloat(document.getElementById('idconcepto_consumo').value);

var parametros = {'xco' : xco, 'xto' : xto, 'xde' : xde, 'xcc' : xcc}

$.ajax({
            //data:  parametros,
            url:   "mi_nuevo.php",
            type:  "post",
            error : function(xhr, status) {
                alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
            },
            success: function(response){
                $("#consumo").val(response)

            },
        }); 



        }
```

espero te ayude, y la marcas como resulta, By: JJ

Comment: gracias por el code, estaba probando pero sale un error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)